# Override parameterless GetUser in custom membershipprovider

Tags: asp.net, .net, membership, membershipuser

Currently i'm using the following code to get my custom MembershipUser, with my custom membershipprovider:

```
FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)User.Identity;
HtCustomUser user = (HtCustomUser) Membership.GetUser(id.Ticket.Name, true);
```

I would like to override the parameterless GetUser() in my custom MembershipProvider, but can't figure out how to get the currently logged in user, from my provider. Currently I have overridden the GetUser(Username) and creates the custom MembershipUser, with data from my data store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always it is alot easier finding the answer, after a question has been asked:

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name
```

Allows me to get the username, directly from the provider, without having to use the client User-object.